# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, typeerror

I've got this simple function that retrieves a value from an existing table. Everytime my application run this function, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined` error. The function is:

```
function getDataCapData(proc, index){
    var cd=document.getElementById("capacityD");
    var i=2;
    while(i<cd.rows.length){
        if(proc.localeCompare(cd.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML)==0) return 1*cd.rows[i].cells[index].innerHTML;
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Am I mistaking something? May this error be related to my application (I mean, i've already encountered this strange issue in the very same application, and solved it with a previous assignment of the "undefined" value)?

EDIT: after some tests, I've discovered that the problem is in  the return value. In fact, if i set `return 1;`, i don't get the error. So, how can this be possible? The table exists, when executing the `localeCompare()` function the values are successfully read, why cannot I read another value and return it?

2nd EDIT: if I console.log the value, instead of returning it, the console correctly displays it. How can it be possible?

3rd EDIT: don't ask me how, but I managed to solve this. My new code is:

```
function getDataCapData(proc, index){
    var cd=document.getElementById("capacityD");
    var i=2;
    while(i<cd.rows.length && proc.localeCompare(cd.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML)!=0) i++;
    return( 1*cd.rows[i].cells[index].innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: Test `proc.localeCompare(cd.rows[i].cells[0]` in `console.log`

Comment: can you show your html ?

Comment: @Rayon, I've tested the localeCompare() function in the console, and it works properly. So the undefined value is the return value?

Comment: @JimmyPage, Do share a Fiddle/executable demo to test..

Comment: Can you change your  return value to 

return (1*cd.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML) and see if error is gone

what is the value of var index anyways ? maybe its an out of range value ..

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, I did not ignore him, I've actually answered 21 mins ago.

Comment: @umer, I tried, but I still get the same error. I've tried `var ret=cd.rows[i].cells[index].innerHTML` too, and I still get this error. I really do not understand why i can read values in the while statement and cannot return a value from the same table.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked your comment. I know it's not excuse but I'm so tired of seeing information requests just ignored. Whatever, have you verified that `console.log(cd.rows[i].cells[index])` is not `undefined`?

Comment: You don't need to excuse, I understand your point of view. I've tried to log the return value, and it is always 1 (values in the table are 0 or >50).

Comment: But the error message doesn't complaint about numbers, it complains about `cd.rows[i].cells[0]` being `undefined`. Have you verified what error claim before going further?

Comment: can you try put up a bracket around like this 

return 1*(cd.rows[i].cells[index].innerHTML)

Comment: Thanks to everybody, it magically solved itself :) solution code in the question above.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out but... For the sake of our sanity, did you eventually run `console.log(cd.rows[i].cells[index])`?

Comment: You are missing answers today :)  I did run this line and log this value (the return value), and i always got "1".

Comment: omg, this question really deserves a -3 score? Have I missed something?

Comment: I had always assumed that `1` referred to the function return value ("log the return value, and it is always 1", "function always returns 1"), not the isolated `cd.rows[i].cells[index]` expression. That's actually weirder because it's supposed to be an object (a DOM element)—I can't figure out how it can be a number :-?

Answer (score 0):

Put a debugger in the while statement. Then open the console with <kbd>f12</kbd>. After that using <kbd>f10</kbd> you can go one step at a time through the code. Somewhere in the object `cd` the `rows[i].cells[0]` element is undefined. Thats why you get this error.

Comment: I swear that the localeCompare always works properly. I think error is in the return value, in fact this function always returns 1.

Comment: @JimmyPage In fact, most browsers will tell you the exact line (often, even the exact column). What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome now

Comment: Line number is in the opposite side of the error message, it might go unnoticed in a wide window ([screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/JF5og9U.png)). You can then click on file name to get sent to more or less the error location ([screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/pmBBcfc.png)). I'm more used to Firefox and Firebug, which I find slightly more intuitive ([screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/IrO07XI.png)).